# High temperature limit of Einstein model for heat capacity

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm struggling to work out the high temperature limit of the Einstein model for heat capacity. The model is $$C_{v}=\frac{3N\hbar^{2}\omega^{2}}{4kT^{2}\sinh^{2}\left(\frac{\hbar \omega}{2kT}\right)}$$

The high temperature limit is for $kT \gg\hbar\omega$ which and my working out is that in the limit that $T \to \infty$ $\sinh \to 0$ so $C_{v}$ is $0$? But the answer is $3Nk$ which I am unsure how to get to.

Comment: Use that  for small $x$, $\sinh x\to x$. Note that you have also a $T$ multiplying the $\sinh$ so you cannot just try simple substitution. Look for a Taylor development.

Comment: You determined the limit incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\lim_{x\to0} \sinh[x] = x$.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a little more details. The limit
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T\sinh(a/T)}$$
cannot be evaluated directly, as $T\to\infty$ and $\sinh(a/T)\to 0$. Rewriting it in terms of $\beta=1/T$, we have
$$\lim_{\beta\to 0}\frac{\beta}{\sinh(a\beta)}$$
of the form $0/0$.

Using l'Hôpital rule
$$\lim_{\beta\to 0}\frac{\beta}{\sinh(a\beta)}=\lim_{\beta\to 0}\frac{1}{a\cosh(a\beta)}=\frac{1}{a}$$
Thus the limit is finite.